# Integral $\int_{0}^{e} \frac{\operatorname{W(x)} - x}{\operatorname{W(x)} + x} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, riemann-zeta, lambert-w, polylogarithm

$$\int_{0}^{e} \frac{\operatorname{W(x)} - x}{\operatorname{W(x)} + x} dx = 2 \operatorname{Li_2(-e)} - e + \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \log(4) + 4 \log(1 + e)≈-0.819168$$

As usual I prefer to know if there is an antiderivative like [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22rangestart%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22integral%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%22%28W%28x%29-%28x%29%29%2F%28W%28x%29%2Bx%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22rangeend%22%7D%20-%3E%22e%22) .So WA gives the result but I would like to understand better .I think that we can use the following substitution :

$$t=xe^x$$

After I'm stuck because of the polylogarithm .

### My question

How to solve this properly ?

Why we have $\zeta(2)$ in the formula ?

Thanks a lot for your comments or answers.

### Update

Performing the substitution $x=te^t$ we get :

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{t - te^t}{t + te^t} dte^t$$

Or 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - e^t}{1 + e^t}(e^t(1+t)) dt$$

Or :
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - e^t}{1 + e^t}(e^t)+te^t \frac{1 - e^t}{1 + e^t}dt$$

Or :

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 +e^t- 2e^t}{1 + e^t}(e^t)+te^t \frac{1+e^t - 2e^t}{1 + e^t}dt$$

Or:
$$\int_{0}^{1} e^t +\frac{- 2e^{t}}{1 + e^t}(e^t)+te^t+ \frac{ - 2te^{2t}}{1 + e^t}dt$$

The problem is :

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{ - 2te^{2t}}{1 + e^t}dt$$

We integrate by parts to get :

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{ - 2te^{2t}}{1 + e^t}dt=[-2te^t\ln(1+e^t)]_0^1-\int_{0}^{1}  - 2(t+1)e^{t}\ln(1 + e^t)dt$$

The problem is :

$$\int_{0}^{1}  - 2(t+1)e^{t}\ln(1 + e^t)dt$$

After this I'm stuck again ...
Oh If we perform the substitution $y=e^t$ in the last integral we get the integral of MHZ .

Comment: You are on the right track. What do you get after substituting $W(x)=t$?

Comment: @Zacky I am on my phone but after the substitution and an integration by parts I can't evaluate this : $\int_{0}^{1}(x+1)e^x\log(e^x+1)dx$.I haven't the tools for (maybe power series?).Anyway thanks for your interest.

Comment: Well, what do you get now if you substitute the obvious term $e^x=t$? Also you might need to mention what definition of dilogarithm are you using, I'm seeing a $\operatorname{Li}_2(-e)$ there.

Comment: @Zacky I think we can use the substitution $y=-x$ and $t=e^{-x}$ and use an integration by parts with the integral representation of the dilogarithm and normally we are done.Is it ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result holds since after some substitutions we have that:$$\int (\log (t)+1) \log (t+1) \, dt=\text{Li}_2(-t)+t+\log (t) ((t+1) \log (t+1)-t)$$
So $$\int_1^e (\log (t)+1) \log (t+1) \, dt=\text{Li}_2(-e)+\frac{\pi ^2}{12}-1+(1+e) \log (1+e)$$

Comment: How do you get these results ?